# Proper way to create a Model/table with multiple child values in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

**As per the comments, I've reworked this question**
I'm new to Laravel 5 and MVC in general, so my question is aimed more at the proper "MVC" way of doing this.

I've got a Model/table (Category/categories), that have name, slug, and id columns. This would be things like "Brand", "Size", "Color". I then need to have multiple values for each of these. For example, "Size" would have "Small", "Medium", and "Large".

I would create a table with columns something like: id, category_id, name/value to accomplish this, and then do a join on the `categories` `id` value.

In Laravel however, I could create a `CategoryValue` model which would have a `belongsTo()` for the `Category` model, and vice versa. This seems like overkill for something that is simply setting/getting list values. Is this the correct Laravel/MVC way of doing it?

On that same note, my `Item` Model will have to store its values for each `Category`. I need to link the `Item` to the `Category` and the `CategoryValue`. At this level, do I create two separate pivot tables? Or do I have one pivot table with three values, such that it would have `item_id`, `category_id`, `categoryValue_id`? I don't want to create excess models and tables.

Comment: You may want to narrow in on a specific question or set of questions. SO isn't really the place for high level database schema design discussions. To help you narrow in, maybe think about your inquiry from the perspective of the Laravel's Eloquent ORM, which is an Active Record style db-abstraction that generally maps your database tables to an object in a 1:1 fashion.

Comment: You should be able to do what you like with structure like this. Take a look at this http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: @MarkFox At your suggestion, I've reworked my question to be more specific about my implementation confusion.